# UX around open data

Tags: info-visualisation, data, data-collection, collaboration

I'm looking to better understand Web User Experience around the opening of data by organizations.

An example is what the world bank has done with their data, see [this](http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog).

So I'm looking for:

1. Notes, best practices on this subject.
2. Good example sites.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question here? "Open Data" is a huge topic; there's hardly any info visualization/etc advice anyone can give on the broad topic of "open" data. Further, open data is just data; Unless there's some specific aspect about disclosing or presenting the issue it's impossible to answer this in the general case.

Comment: Dear @BenBrocka, the answer below is really what I was looking for. Somehow, someone has been able to answer a question deemed "impossible to answer". Thank you for spending 5 seconds looking at a valid question and sentencing it to death. I got my answer from this brave soul but I'll delete my question tomorrow -- you win -- Religious fanaticism on stackexchange reaches new heights. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the UK there are various attempts. http://www.data.gov.uk/ is the main one as they are trying to open up the government data.

All statistical data is posted here by www.statistics.gov.uk.  The UKSA is responsibile for all statistical data from government, but how it all work is stupidly complex.

Tim (I invented the internet) Bernes Lee is important in all of this with this typo ridden entry http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html  I have the mug!

Possibly better discussed here http://5stardata.info/

You have timed this well as the Census data just came out in the UK.  (If you can cope with the website) http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/census/2011-census/key-statistics-for-local-authorities-in-england-and-wales/index.html

There is even more information about XML and sharing with local government within UK, but I can't place my hands on it.

A bit low tech maybe but certainly open http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/Info.do?page=nde.htm

In the US they have a similar complex statistical system and we have tried to copy them, theres is www.data.gov.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @the-question, many thanks for the answer, this is what I was looking for. I was going to delete the question because some religious have closed it and rated it negatively but then I think your hard work will be lost. So for now I've decided to keep it :-). Once again thanks.